# How to make specific programs use wireguard in arch linux?

Tags: arch-linux, vpn

I'd like to have only one program run through a wireguard config I have stored at `/etc/wireguard/config.conf`, and all the other programs run through the normal IP address.

I've found [this page in the wireguard use on routing](https://www.wireguard.com/netns/), which suggests using namespaces, but when I try to run some of the commands, such as

```
sudo ip link set wlp2s0 netns physical
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

Suggesting this can't be done through arch linux. Has anyone found a way to get specific programs to run through wireguard?

---

I tried the above tutorial on a different machine, and I get the following error when trying to load my wireguard config.

`wg setconf wgvpn0 /etc/wireguard/my_vpn.conf` : invalid format, yet the same config works perfectly when using `wg-quick up`

Side point, does anyone know of any issue tracking system for wireguard? The questions I submit to their mailing list aren't publicly available.

Comment: What does your wireguard config look like, and what output do you get from `# lsns -l`?

Comment: lsns -l just has a bunch of entries for syncthing only, and wireguard config looks like:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 
Address = 
DNS =

[Peer]
PublicKey = 
AllowedIPs =
Endpoint =
```

Comment: Does the `wlp2s0` interface exists on your system? It seems that it's an Wifi interface, not a wireguard one (usually `wg0`). Please post the `ip link list` of your system after connecting to that vpn...

Comment: there is a third one for wireguard after connecting to it.

Comment: From the [very same page you link](https://www.wireguard.com/netns/#the-new-namespace-solution), quoting: "`# iw phy phy0 set netns name physical` (Note that wireless devices must be moved using `iw` and by specifying the physical device `phy0`.)" .

Comment: I don't see evidence to support the current close-votes indicating "off-topic, can't reproduced."  It seems to *me* from A.B.'s comment that there's a potential answer waiting here...

Comment: @JeffSchaller OP tried on the wireless device the command  from the wireguard page made for the ethernet device, while that page gave explicitly an example for ethernet followed by a different example for wireless (the one I wrote), the line right after. Should I just answer this? I assumed it went with typo etc. Somebody else following the guide shouldn't make the same mistake, so this question doesn't look very useful

Comment: Oh well I'll write it

Comment: @JeffSchaller well my answer didn't seem that useful afterward...

Comment: It seemed worth a try, from the point of view of the close-vote queue; thanks for trying!

Answer (score 2):

From the [wireguard.com's link provided in OP's question](https://www.wireguard.com/netns/), specifically in [The New Namespace Solution](https://www.wireguard.com/netns/#the-new-namespace-solution), it's explained how to move physical interfaces, with an ethernet and a wireless example, bold emphasis mine:

> [image: Physical Network Namespace Diagram]
>   First we create the "physical" network namespace:
>
> ```
> # ip netns add physical
> ```
>
> Now we move `eth0` and `wlan0` into the "physical" namespace:
>
> ```
> # ip link set eth0 netns physical
> # iw phy phy0 set netns name physical
> ```
>
> (**Note that wireless devices must be moved using `iw` and by
>   specifying the physical device `phy0`.**)

it appears OP read the first `ip link set ... netns` command, but didn't see that the second command was needed instead for a wireless device, as noted.

[`iw`'s manual page](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/iw/iw.8) is scarce, but `iw --help` includes:

> ```
>    phy <phyname> set netns { <pid> | name <nsname> }
>             Put this wireless device into a different network namespace:
>                 <pid>    - change network namespace by process id
>                 <nsname> - change network namespace by name from /run/netns
>                            or by absolute path (man ip-netns)
> ```

Some drivers might not yet be compatible with network namespaces. This output is required for it to work:

```
$ sudo iw phy0 info|grep netns
         * set_wiphy_netns
```

Assuming there's only one simple wireless device, `wlp2s0` is handled by `iw` via its `phy0` counterpart, so won't appear at all in the command. This must be used:

```
sudo iw phy phy0 set netns name physical
```

Comment: After I run those two commands, it disconnects my wireless connection, and my `ip addr` command no longer shows my wireless card. I can only recover by running: `sudo ip netns delete physical` `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`

Comment: Also the `wg setconf wgvpn0 /etc/wireguard/my_vpn.conf` command fails, saying its an invalid format, yet it works perfectly when using `wg-quick up`. I really wish wireguard had an open issue tracking system.

Comment: It's expected to lose access (from init namespace) to the interface when you move it: no bug or issue. Maybe you didn't unsterstand the goal of the tutorial. As for the my_vpn.conf I see no trace of it, nor any trace of NetworkManager. Are you still following the tutorial you linked?

Comment: So how do I get access then? This answer still doesn't help me solve my overall goal, getting specific programs to use wireguard in arch linux. Also yes I'm still trying to follow their tutorial, although it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to move your physical interfaces to a different namespace for this purpose.  Just put the wireguard device in another namespace and use `ip netns exec <NAMESPACE> command arg1 arg2 ...`

Comment: @TavianBarnes There are various methods to achieve the same goal. I was pointing that OP didn't read correctly the documentation made by the WireGuard's author about moving a physical interface to a different namespace when the interface is a wifi interface instead of any other interface such as an ethernet interface. If this is given as an example of use by WireGuard's author himself, I can only assume this can sometimes make sense.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the UID of the program / user running the program;
2. Send it in the wireguard tunnel using `iptables`.

[EDIT]
For exemple, here i'm redirecting exemple_app (replace it with the program you want) trafic to tor (it's from one of my projects). Just change some things and redirect the trafic into your wireguard tunnel (theres many examples on the internet).

```
#!/bin/sh
# Vars
_trans_port="9040"
_dns_port="5353"
_exemple_app_uid=`id -u exemple_app`
#_tor_uid=`id -u debian-tor`
#_resv_iana="0.0.0.0/8 100.64.0.0/10 169.254.0.0/16 192.0.0.0/24 192.0.2.0/24 192.88.99.0/24 198.18.0.0/15 198.51.100.0/24 203.0.113.0/24 224.0.0.0/4 240.0.0.0/4 255.255.255.255/32"
#_non_tor="127.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16"
_out_if="wlan0"
_gateway="192.168.1.1"
_local_network="192.168.1.0/24"

# Remove all the iptables rules
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X

# Set up the policies
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
ip6tables -P INPUT DROP
ip6tables -P FORWARD DROP
ip6tables -P OUTPUT DROP

# Redirect trafic through Tor
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner $_exemple_app_uid -m tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports $_trans_port
# redirect DNS requests through Tor
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp -m owner --uid-owner $_exemple_app_uid -m udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports $_dns_port
# Drop the rest
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner $_exemple_app_uid -j LOG --log-prefix "[exemple_app tcp drop] " --log-level 7 --log-uid
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner $_exemple_app_uid -j DROP
```

Create a systemd service which executes the script on boot.

Comment: How do I do that?